# Kaminari Pagination numbers are not displayed

Tags: kaminari

My problem is that the pagination with kaminari is not working if I set the pagination greater than 1. The pagination bar is displayed only if I set 1 record per page.
If I set:

```
@p.result.page(params[:page]).per(1)
```

I can see the pagination bar (but there are only 2 pages, with one record each, to browse..)

If I set:

```
@p.result.page(params[:page]).per(2) (or more)
```

The bar is not visible but I can see 2 records (or more) in the table.

Well: I've found that the issue is due to the scope I have in patient model.
If I don't use "basic_info", it works.

```
@p = Patient.basic_info.ransack(params[:q]) (No pagination bar)
@p = Patient.ransack(params[:q]) (it works)
```

Why..?

In model patient.rb I have:

```
scope :basic_info, -> { 
    self.left_joins(hospitalizations: :surgery)
    .distinct
    .select("patients.id,first_name, 
    last_name, 
    gender,  
    MAX(surgeries.surgery_date) as most_recent_surgery")
    .group("patients.id, first_name, last_name, gender")
}
```

In patients_controller.rb:

```
@p = Patient.basic_info.ransack(params[:q])
@patients = @p.result.page(params[:page]).per(2)
```

Patient's index.html.erb:

```
<tbody>
    <% @patients.each do |patient| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= patient.first_name %></td>
            <td><%= patient.last_name %></td>
            <td><%= patient.gender %></td>
            <td>
            <% if patient.most_recent_surgery %>
                <%= patient.most_recent_surgery.to_time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') %>
            <% end %></td>
            <td class="centra"><%= link_to t('edit'), edit_patient_path(patient) %></td>
            <td class="centra"><%= link_to t('delete'), patient, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Eliminazione irreversibile. Continuare?' } %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>

<div style="text-align:center;"><%= paginate @patients %></div>
```

The resulting records are limited (I can see only two rows in my datatables view) and I got no errors but the pagination is not displayed.

I'm using Rails 5.02

How can I fix this issue?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution [here](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/pull/573#pullrequestreview-8745554).

Changing the group by clause in the "basic_info" scope solved the issue:

From

```
.group("patients.id, first_name, last_name, gender")
```

To

group(:id, :first_name, :last_name, :gender)